# How to call function repetitively in Android app?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, time, timer

i'm using camera in my android app and I want to take a picture every - 30 sec. for example. For intervals i want to use difference between previous time and current time System.currentTimeMillis() or timeout. But i don't know how to make function to being called repetitively. Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

You need multithreading. If you are calling the ext. activity, it uses UI, so you should not use Timer. Handler only. Many java classes for multithreading are not for work with the Android UI. Use this class:

```
import android.os.Handler;


/**
* Examples of use:
* 
*   Waiter(Runnable call, 30000); - in the calling method
*
* @author Petr Gangnus
*/
public class Waiter {
    /**
     * the handler that works instead of timer and supports UI
     */
    static private Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable task;

    public Waiter(Runnable task,long time){
        this.task=task;
        handler.removeCallbacks(task);
        handler.postDelayed(task, time);
    }

    public void stopWaiting(){
        handler.removeCallbacks(task);
    }

}

// setting the task called - in the calling method
final private Runnable call = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ...;
    }
};
```

Comment: Is it really multithreading nescessary? Now i have picture taken on button cliick listener and i want to run it independently.

Comment: How do you want to wait? One thread is waiting, the other is the called activity of the other(camera) application. Really, Android is all threads. The simple thread classes could be used for algirithmic threads(non-ui), Handlers and others - for UI threads.

Comment: Any example, even quasicode, of solution you suggest? How about simply  - for the first time function taking picture triggered by the button and then at the PictureCallback trigered by buttonClick.performClick()?

Comment: In the code I already attached the clockfaces are refreshed every refreshStep msec. (set by start()). Simply put there your camera call instead of textViews refresh.

Comment: I have put here an easier, shorter example

Answer (score 1):

When you want to perform any task Periodically, then TimerTask class is best. Checkout a very easy example [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/UsejavautilTimertoscheduleatasktoexecuteonce5secondshavepassed.htm). In its run method you can put your coded which you want to perform periodically. You can also give the time interval while scheduling it.

Comment: It is nice to show examples with  System.out.println("Time's up!");, but he needs to call activities. Look around the site here - Timer is *not* safe to use in UI. And pressing buttons and calling activities is UI. You should use Handler instead. Simple ways simply won't work here.